# Bootstrap columns doesn't behave properly in Google Chrome Inspector

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, google-chrome, bootstrap-4, inspector

It seems like when I'm trying to test it in Chrome inspector it's not responding as it should according to the code (the columns shrink) However, it works when I'm scaling the Chrome's window or in Firefox/Edge/Explorer's inspectors.

Kind of trivial problem but it's upsetting since I've got used to using mainly Chrome, or maybe it is a grave problem which I don't understand?

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pl-PL">

<head>
    <title>Bootstrap tutorial</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="description" content="Ucze sie bootstrapa na tutku z yt">
    <link rel="icon" href="boot.ico" type="image/x-icon">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <meta name="viewport" content" width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE-edge">
</head>

<body>

    <div class="container">

        <div class="row">

            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">

                <h4>Column 1</h4>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                <h4>Column 2</h4>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                <h4>Column 3</h4>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                <h4>Column 4</h4>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>






















    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

- [Chrome inspector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1MyRn.png)
- [Shrinking the window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oKzCS.png)

Comment: Your code seems to be correct. Can you post a screenshot of viewing this in Chrome?

Comment: yea, I've edited the post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot about `=` char in meta viewport.
Change:

```
<meta name="viewport" content" width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

To:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Comment: Thanks! It seems that was the issue

Answer (score 0):

You didn't add = in meta tag for content it should be `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">` seems other browsers tend to be more forgiving